# Twitter API - STTwitter library: Unhandled authentication challenge type - NSURLAuthenticationMethodOAuth2

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter, sttwitter

The method I'm using is:

```
[STTwitterAPIWrapper twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerName:@"<Value>" consumerKey:@"<Value>" consumerSecret:@"<Value>" username:@"<Value>" password:@"<Value>"];
```

When I'm using the example given:

```
consumerName:'TweetDeck',
consumerKey:'yT577ApRtZw51q4NPMPPOQ'
```

as parameters, it works and returns Twitter results. When I'm using my own app's consumerName, consumerKey and consumerSecret it returns the error below.

The error log is:

```
Unhandled authentication challenge type - NSURLAuthenticationMethodOAuth2
-- Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0xa6d4fb0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token}
```

Something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [README](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/README.md), your consumer tokens are probably not xAuth-enabled. You can read [more on this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth) on Twitter website and ask Twitter to enable the xAuth authentication process for your consumer tokens.